# How to build a file manager for file stored on cloud with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, cloud, file-manager

If I give the user a space on my server to save their files.

Is there an API or better a Demo for adding capability for the user to manage his files, move, rename, add and delete. And opening the files using local software, in way that saves the files onces the file is closed. 
Like word document, when he click on it it will open with MS Word, and when he close and save upload the local temp file without user intervention.

if not asp.net any other technology.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for **[Microsoft SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint)** Site.

SharePoint can be used to provide **intranet portals, document & file management, collaboration, social networks, extranets, websites, enterprise search, and business intelligence**. It also has capabilities around system integration, process integration, and workflow automation.